# (VBA) Open multiple hyperlinks at once if link does not equal "(blank)"

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create some VBA code that opens multiple hyperlinks at once.

Sheet5 of my workbook contains a pivot table and in column "M" or pivotfield "Attachments" contains the link I want to hyperlink.

The link looks something like this:

"C:\Users\J_Doe\Documents\JDoe\Documents\FM200 Annual- Oct 2016.pdf"

Being a pivot table, if there is no hyperlink already in this field, the field will display "(blank)". Obviously these should not be opened.
So I'd like my code to say something along the lines of "Open all hyperlinks in this field that do not equal "(blank)".

Can anyone assist? I don't even really know where to begin.

---

**UPDATE**

This is my code right now:

```
Sub LaunchMultipleURLs()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheet2.Range("M:M")
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r.Cells
        c.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=True
    Next c
End Sub
```

However, the pivot table link in column M isn't an actual link.It's just the location of the file being accessed, so running this code by itself does nothing.

What I've been doing is leaving the link location like this:

"C:\Users\J_Doe\Documents\JDoe\Documents\FM200 Annual- Oct 2016.pdf"

That way, I can just reference the pivot table by doing something like "=hyperlink(M1)" and I can open the file that way. However, this only works for cell M1. If there are links in M2 and onwards, I can't open them without some sort of VBA.

Comment: *at once* is impossible. *in sequence* is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi David, I've added an update that includes the code that I am working with so far

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx
Launch it via Shell()?

Comment: Is this a relative path (i.e., the "link" file is in the same folder as the Excel file)? If not, you need to fix the path, because what I see is not a full/canonical file path.

Comment: Good point. I guess the file path would be more like: "C:\Users\J_Doe\Documents\JDoe\Documents\FM200 Annual- Oct 2016.pdf"